# "laravel homestead vagrant up errors"

Tags: laravel

I am trying to set up Laravel Homestead environment. When I try to launch the vagrant box I get an error.

> C:\Users\ONYIA\Homestead>vagrant up
>   C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/psych.rb:377:in `parse': (<unknown>): did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping at line 13 column 6 (Psych::SyntaxError)
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/psych.rb:377:in`parse_stream'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/psych.rb:325:in `parse'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/psych.rb:252:in`load'
>           from C:/Users/ONYIA/Homestead/Vagrantfile:29:in `block in <top (required)>'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.6/gems/vagrant-2.2.6/lib/vagrant/config/v2/loader.rb:37:in`load'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.6/gems/vagrant-2.2.6/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:126:in `block (2 levels) in load'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.6/gems/vagrant-2.2.6/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:119:in`each'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.6/gems/vagrant-2.2.6/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:119:in `block in load'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.6/gems/vagrant-2.2.6/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:116:in`each'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.6/gems/vagrant-2.2.6/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:116:in `load'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.6/gems/vagrant-2.2.6/lib/vagrant/vagrantfile.rb:29:in`initialize'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.6/gems/vagrant-2.2.6/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:792:in `new'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.6/gems/vagrant-2.2.6/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:792:in`vagrantfile'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.6/gems/vagrant-2.2.6/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:973:in `process_configured_plugins'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.6/gems/vagrant-2.2.6/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:178:in`initialize'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.6/gems/vagrant-2.2.6/bin/vagrant:145:in `new'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.6/gems/vagrant-2.2.6/bin/vagrant:145:in`'

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to narrow this down specifically to your issue without a lot more information, such as how you provisioned the box, some environment info, etc.

However, I have run into a similar error that may be helpful to you.  In my case, there was an extra space in my `yaml` file before a key value.  Look through your initialization files -- however you have set this up, be it `yaml` or `json`, or whatever -- and check for spaces before a key in that file.

As an example, **in Laravel's .env file**, this might cause a similar issue:

```
APP_KEY =  J3b0MXEWRrqf3DYvwmpYtsbGXv3I2g89U   // <-- shouldn't have spaces
// Should be more like:
APP_KEY=J3b0MXEWRrqf3DYvwmpYtsbGXv3I2g89U
```

Not a real key :)

Another place this turns up is sometimes with missing " `'` " apostrophies.  Check your environment files and make sure all of your quoted items are closed off.

Hope this helps

Comment: I had got same errors & i can confirm it's caused by syntax errors in `.yaml` file.